# Strings containing `{` needs to be escaped. Start the string with `{}`"

Tags: string, xamarin.forms, string-formatting

In my Xamarin project I have a Label that formats a Date Value. I updated some Xamarin Nuget packages and now I'm getting the following error:

> Strings containing `{` needs to be escaped. Start the string with
>   `{}`"

The Label on the page is a pretty simple `StringFormat`

```
<Label Text="{Binding Booking.ScheduledDeparture, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}"/>
```

Any ideas how I can resolve this error. I've tried adding `@` to the start of the `StringFormat` but that didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried adding `{}`before the rest of the string? `'{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'`

Comment: Yeah, I've did this a few minutes and it resolved the issue on VS. Just about to load up the app and see if everything is okay. If you want to add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Glad it seems to work, I've added an answer linking to some documentation. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `{}` before a string that starts with a `{` this should escape it. So `'{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'`.
For more documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/xaml-services/escape-sequence-markup-extension